# AWS Cognito : Unable to construct an endpoint for cognito-identity in region None

Tags: authentication, mobile, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cognito

I use an [AWS Cognito CLI command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-identity/index.html) syntactically exact to

```
aws cognito-identity get-open-id-token-for-developer-identity --identity-pool-id eu-west-1:c1b83398-09xx-4x38-b10x-2346x1xdc1b --logins login.mywebsite.myappname=johndoe@example.com
```

Said command has successfully returned tokens previously.

I am now receiving the error "Unable to construct an endpoint for cognito-identity in region None"

I have retired this with various cognito identity pools; swapping the identity-pool-id and logins as appropriate. Any ideas?

PS : If I use the CLI command describe-identity-pool

e.g. 
aws cognito-identity describe-identity-pool --identity-pool-id eu-west-1:c1b83398-09xx-4x38-b10x-2346x1xdc1

I receive the same error message.

X-posted on [Aws Cognito Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=587992&#587992)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like region is missing from your aws configuration.
Can you please run 'aws configure' and provide region as 'eu-west-1' as your identity pool belongs to this region.

Comment: Cheers Vinay - apologies for the entry level mistake. I had configured it previously.